# AnimatorSet does not repeat even after using it inside a callback

Tags: android, animation

I'm unable to figure out what is wrong with this piece of code. I play two `Animator`s together by calling the `AnimatorSet.playTogether()` method. But the `onAnimationEnd()` callback is called only ONCE. Why is this happening?

```
indeterminateAnimatorSet.addListener(object: AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
        indeterminateAnimatorSet.start() // <= This one is called only ONCE!
    }
})

indeterminateAnimatorSet.start() // <= 1st call here to start the animation
```

PS: I have no cancel / end calls.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late, but what worked for me is using a handler in `onAnimationEnd()`

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animatorSet.start();
        }
    });
}
```

This should not be necessary, as `onAnimationEnd()` executes on the main thread already, but this is what did it for me.